# Merging dictionaries in specific order

Tags: python, dictionary, merge, pickle

I post here because I cannot find the answer of my problem.

Let me explain : I am trying to do multi-processing tasks.
I have 10 workers, each one returns a dictionary, the values are lists with 3 elements, 2 ints and 1 list :

For example :

worker 0  returns  `{0 : [3,15, [[0,1,1], [1,1,0]] , 2 : [11,14, [[3,0,1], [1,4,2]]}`

worker 1 returns `{0 : [6,8, [[4,1,7], [5,8,8]] , 2 : [19,27, [[6,1,11], [4,4,2]]}`

worker 2 returns `{0 : [13, 7, [[0,1,1], [1,1,0]], 2 : [7, 3, [[3,0,1], [5,3,1]]}`

---

These dictionaries are stored in different pickle files.

In that case, I have 2 differents keys, so I want 2 dictionaries (but the number is a variable).

they should look like that :

`d1 = {0 : [X ,Y, [[0,1,1], [4,1,7],[0,1,1],[1,1,0],[5,8,8],[1,1,0] }`

`d1 = {2 : [X ,Y, [[0,1,1], [4,1,7],[0,1,1],[1,1,0],[5,8,8],[1,1,0] }`

X is the sum of the first elements = 3 + 6 + 13 = 22

Y is the sum of second elements = 15 + 8 + 7 =30

Notice that the lists elements of the list are interlaced, not concatenate, I must loop on the workers and take one element each time.

my code starts like that :

```
def mergeAnalysis(outPath, nbWorkers):
        for i in range(nbWorkers):
            with open(os.path.join(outPath, "ERROR_TEMP{}.p".format(i)), 'rb') as fichier:
                dictlist.append(pickle.load(fichier))
```

dictlist is the list of dictionaries.

If anyone have an idea to do that ?
Thank you very much for your help

edit : I tried to extract the values of the dictionnaries :

```
for j in range(0,len(dictlist)):
    for k1 in dictlist[j].keys():
        a = dictlist[j].get(k1)
```

Comment: What is your question? No one wants to debug your code for you.

Comment: My question is how to do that properly, My code doesnt need to be debugged, as it is just a start, loading my pickle files and creating a list of dictionnaries.

Comment: The code you've provided is not really relevant. What have you tried to actually solve your problem of merging the dictionaries according to your requirements? There are probably thousands of questions similar to this. What have you been able to find in your research? Please see [ask].

Comment: Do not post code in the comments, it is completely unreadable. Edit your question and add it there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a list of outputs your worker are returning. Assuming the order may matter so this list has a specific order. Basically, assuming you have this:

```
worker_outputs = [
    {0: [3, 15, [[0, 1, 1], [1, 1, 0]]], 2: [11, 14, [[3, 0, 1],  [1, 4, 2]]]},
    {0: [6, 8,  [[4, 1, 7], [5, 8, 8]]], 2: [19, 27, [[6, 1, 11], [4, 4, 2]]]},
    {0: [13, 7, [[0, 1, 1], [1, 1, 0]]], 2: [7,  3,  [[3, 0, 1],  [5, 3, 1]]]},
]
```

Iterating through the keys of your worker outputs will make it far easier to solve this one.

```
import pprint
keys = set(k for output in worker_outputs for k in output)

results = {}
for key in keys:
    outputs_with_key = [output[key] for output in worker_outputs if key in output]

    results[key] = [
        sum(l[0] for l in outputs_with_key),
        sum(l[1] for l in outputs_with_key),
        zip(*(l[2] for l in outputs_with_key)),
    ]

pprint.pprint(results)
```

Comment: Thank you ! Exactly what I asked for.